# アプリを起動する際にSafariを起動させる訳は何ででしょうか？

Tags: ios, safari

iPhoneで新規のゲームを起動する際に、Safariが起動されてそこからアプリが起動する場合がありますが、あれは何の為でしょうか？

Answer (score 3, accepted):

主に広告などのSDKによる、ユーザーのトラッキングのために使われています。もともとは絶対に変わらないIDとしてUDIDがあり、トラッキング目的にそれが使われていたため、UDIDはアプリケーションから取得できなくなりました。

代わりに、ベンダーIDや広告IDを使わなければなりませんが、ベンダーIDはアプリケーション提供元を超えてユーザーを識別することができませんし、広告IDはユーザーが変更することが可能です。

そのため、ベンダーの垣根を超えてユーザーを識別する方法として、ブラウザのクッキーを利用する方法が多くの広告SDKでは用いられています。

#### 参考リンク

- [Appleがクッキーを利用しているアプリを拒絶へ: Ad Identifierへの統一がねらい](http://jp.techcrunch.com/2013/02/26/20130225apple-rejecting-apps-using-cookie-tracking-methods-signaling-push-to-its-own-ad-identifier-technology-is-now-underway/)
- [Apple、クッキーを利用したアプリを拒否する方針に！ 起動した時に一瞬だけSafariが開くアプリはダメ](http://www.appps.jp/2030872/)